# Summing a 1D array with a col of a 2D array

Tags: python, numpy

I wonder why this question never came up by somebody else(maybe its so stupid but I need it) and I couldn't figure it out myself. I want to add a 1D array to a specific column or row of  a 2D array. The way I did it here sounds really stupid. I don't want to keep the original copy of `a` in this following example untouched. Is there any other way of doing it?

```
import numpy as np
a=np.arange(9).reshape((3,3))
b=np.arange(3)
print a 
print b
print a+np.vstack((np.zeros(3),b,np.zeros(3))).T
```

output:

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
[0 1 2]
[[ 0.  1.  2.]
 [ 3.  5.  5.]
 [ 6.  9.  8.]]
```

**EDIT**: To keep it fancy, I want to do this in one-liner, since this is a calculation in the middle of evaluating a `lambda` function! In any case other solutions are very welcomed.

Comment: @BrianCain, the problem is not getting the column perse. Its that when you get it you are not overwriting it in its real place :|

Comment: I'm not understanding the "1-liner" constraint.  Just turn your lambda into a regular function ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you mean?

```
a[:, 1] += b

print(a)
#array([[0, 1, 2],
#       [3, 5, 5],
#       [6, 9, 8]])
```

---

EDIT: to keep the original array untouched:

```
c = a.copy()
c[:, 1] += b
```

---

EDIT2: if you really want an one-liner:

```
a + np.repeat(b, a.shape[1]).reshape(a.shape)*[0,1,0]
```

Comment: That does do the job but its strange that there is no built in function for that. Thanks anyways.

Comment: I explained my reasons in comments for DSM. Thanks anyways. I was just trying to keep things condensed....

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
def cadd(arr, slicer, val):
    arr = arr.copy()
    arr[slicer] += val
    return arr
```

After which:

```
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> cadd(a, np.s_[:, 1], b)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 5, 5],
       [6, 9, 8]])
>>> cadd(a, np.s_[1, :], b)
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 5, 7],
       [6, 7, 8]])
>>> a
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

where I've used `np.s_` to make a multidimensional slice object conveniently.  With enough trickery you could probably make this a one-liner, but why?

Comment: I was just trying to keep everything short and beautiful. I need to evaluate a function on an argument of another one. The only way to do this is a one-liner. I just gave up and went with a normal solution, but thanks for the effort.

Comment: "The only way to do this is a one-liner."  That won't become true no matter how many times you say it, I'm afraid.

Comment: ha ha :)
ok I mean to do it inside the container for argument; either I have to call another function there or should do it inside the block of the the final function that I am evaluating.